# A Puzzle on PAXOS Algorithm for consensus

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system, distributed-transactions

Say, 5 nodes (with ids 1..5) contribute to a distributed system. During the process of reaching consensus, a proposal is suggested by node 4 with a proposal number 103. In similar fashion, a proposal is suggested by node 3 with a proposal number 111. Node 2 being a malicious node immediately makes another proposal with a proposal number 117. What will be the final state of the system after the consensus is reached (consider PAXOS as the underlying consensus algorithm)?

1. Proposal 103 from node 1 will be considered finally
2. Blocking proposal 117 and accepting proposal 111 finally
3. Proposal 117 from node 1 will be considered finally
4. Nodes 2, 3, and 5 will wait for sometime and one of them will become a proposer

According to me it is none of the above, but still I need some inputs to confirm if am missing any analysis in the PAXOS Algorithm.

Comment: the question has insufficient information to determine the outcome. paxos is safe regardless of messages being reordered on the wire or lost. so you need to say which acceptors got which message when and who got their replies when to determine the outcome. Paxos doesn't guarantee progress so the likely outcome of what you describe is that the round is failed.

Comment: It is possible that messages are delayed, or processes are stalled and resume, or r network drops messages. so it is perfectly possible that the messages you describe are from correct nodes just trying to run Paxos under adverse conditions with none of them being malicious.